# Flutter: ListView.Builder type of Map<String,T>

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have Drop down of Sports list and whenever user select sports from Dropdown, The selected sports is stored in `Map` and will be updated in ListView so that user can see the selected sports. I'm able to add Sport in the map while selecting from the drop-down and getting the correct length of selected sports but I Have to show in `ListView`, it is showing null value when I'm trying to get sports name at index. How can I display Selected sports from the map in listview items

```
Map<String,Sports> _selectedSports = new Map<String,Sports>();

ListView.builder(
shrinkWrap: true,
physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
itemCount: _selectedSports!=null?_selectedSports.length:0, itemBuilder: 
(BuildContext ctxt, int index) {return new Text('Sports 
${_selectedSports[index].names}');})// showing null here



 ${_selectedSports['1'].names}// but it is returning value by key
```

I'm successfully adding items in map from `onChanged` of drop down

```
void changedDropDownSportsItems(Sports selectedSports) {
     print("Selected Sport ${selectedSports.names}");
     _selectedSports[selectedSports.id.toString()] = selectedSports;
    setState(() {
      _currentSportsBar  = selectedSports;
      _selectedSports;
      print("Selected Sports size ${_selectedSports.length}");

    });
  }
```

When I'm trying to get value by key it returns name but from index it returns null.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**
try this

```
 Column(
            children: _selectedSports.values
                .toList()
                .map((value) => Text('Sports ${value.names}'))
                .toList())
```

Comment: Actually, `index` is not the key of `map`  and i have already tried this, still showing null.

Comment: I thought id is like a index from 0 to x ,  selectedSports.id.toString(). 
You can't use this if the index is not from 0 to something 
_selectedSports[index].names}. Because what itemBuilder is returning an index from 0 to _selectedSports.length